# Convert pdf to text without creating a file

Tags: python, pdf, text

I want to download pdf files from a website and work with the text. But, I don't want to create a pdf file and then convert it to text. I use python request. Is there any way to get the text directly after the following code?

`res = requests.get(url, timeout=None)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting text from a PDF file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837707/extracting-text-from-a-pdf-file-using-python)

Comment: I'd say it isn't a duplicate of ^, because OP is asking "Can I do this...?" And the answer is no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> AFAIK, you will have to at least create a temp file so that you can
>   perform your process.

You can use the following code which takes / reads a PDF file and converts it to a TEXT file.
This makes use of PDFMINER and Python 3.7.

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import HTMLConverter,TextConverter,XMLConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
import io

def convert(case,fname, pages=None):
    if not pages:
        pagenums = set()
    else:
        pagenums = set(pages)
    manager = PDFResourceManager()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    caching = True
    output = io.StringIO()
    converter = TextConverter(manager, output, codec=codec, laparams=LAParams())
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(manager, converter)
    infile = open(fname, 'rb')
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(infile, pagenums, caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

    convertedPDF = output.getvalue()
    print(convertedPDF)

    infile.close()
    converter.close()
    output.close()
    return convertedPDF
```

Main function to call the above program:

```
import os
import converter
import sys, getopt

class ConvertMultiple:
    def convert_multiple(pdf_dir, txt_dir):
        if pdf_dir == "": pdf_dir = os.getcwd() + "\\"  # if no pdfDir passed in
        for pdf in os.listdir(pdf_dir):  # iterate through pdfs in pdf directory
            print("File name is %s", os.path.basename(pdf))
            file_extension = pdf.split(".")[-1]
            print("file extension is %s", file_extension)
            if file_extension == "pdf":
                pdf_file_name = pdf_dir + pdf
                path = 'E:/pdf/' + os.path.basename(pdf)
                print(path)
                text = converter.convert('text', path)  # get string of text content of pdf
                text_file_name = txt_dir + pdf + ".txt"
                text_file = open(text_file_name, "w")  # make text file
                text_file.write(text)  # write text to text file


pdf_dir = "E:/pdf"
txt_dir = "E:/text"
ConvertMultiple.convert_multiple(pdf_dir, txt_dir)
```

Of course you can tune it some more and may be some more room for improvement, but this thing certainly works.

> Just make sure instead of providing pdf folder  provide a temp pdf
>   file directly.

Hope this helps you..Happy Coding!

Answer (score 2):

PyPDF2 works fine  If all you want is the text

Install the PyPDF2 package https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/ on anaconda terminal (or)  cmd prompt

`pip install PyPDF2`

You can use the following code which takes/reads a PDF file and converts it to a TEXT file

```
import PyPDF2
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
def getTextPDF(pdfFileName,password=''):
    pdf_file=open(pdfFileName,'rb')
    read_pdf=PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
    if password !='':
        read_pdf.decrypt(password)
    text=[]
    for i in range(0,read_pdf.getNumPages()):
        text.append(read_pdf.getPage(i).extractText())
    return ('\n'.join (text).replace("\n",''))


getText2PDF('0001.pdf')
```

Works great for me

Answer (score 1):

If your pdf file is in AWS S3(Simple Storage Service), Pass the Unsigned URL.

```
import boto3 
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader 
from io import BytesIO


def extract_PDF(url): #URL where the pdf is stored online

    CF="https://<Bucket_name>.<Website>.com/"
    object_name = url.replace(CF,'')
    bucket_name="<Bucket_name>.<Website>.com"

    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    obj = s3.Object(bucket_name, object_name)
    fs = obj.get()['Body'].read()
    pdfFile = PdfFileReader(BytesIO(fs))

    text=""
    for page_no in range(len(pdfFile.pages)):
        page = pdfFile.getPage(page_no)
        text += page.extractText()
    text = text.replace('\n','')
    text = text.replace('  ','')
    return text
```

Comment: Probably more helpful to this question to drop anything regarding S3, which confuses what’s relevant, and rewrite this to request a regular URL, per the original question that uses the `requests.get()` method.