# What is the best Python library to use for generating XML from text/PDF in Python?

Tags: python, xml, machine-learning, text-processing

I am trying to automate scientific PDF to XML using Python. I would like to know: is there any Python library that can generate XML from text or from PDF documents?

Answer (score 2):

You can use textract to read a pdf file, 
for details: [Extracting text from a PDF file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837707/extracting-text-from-a-pdf-file-using-python)
once you have your text in a variable use ElementTrees to write properly formatted XML.