# Read a pdf file and store the words in a list using python

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, pypdf

I am trying to parse a pdf document and extract values against certain keywords and I am doing it step by step. Below is the code that I have come up so far where I am trying to create a list of words that match the keywords. However the output that I get is that a complete line is being considered as word.

```
import PyPDF2,nltk
import easytextract
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords


pdfFileObj = open('C:\\mydoc.pdf','rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
num_pages = pdfReader.numPages
count = 0
text = ""
while count < num_pages:
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(count)
    count +=1
    text += pageObj.extractText()

keywords = [word for word in word_tokenize(text,'english',False)]
print(keywords)
```

Output=`['OfficeNotice', 'AbcBANKLTD', 'ThisOfferingNoticerelatestothe']`
my expected output is as below

```
['Office','Notice','Abc','BANK','LTD','This','Offering','Notice','relates','to','the']
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the [documentation of `extractText` method](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PageObject.html#PyPDF2.pdf.PageObject.extractText) you use:

> Locate all text drawing commands, in the order they are provided in
>   the content stream, and extract the text. This **works well for some PDF
>   files, but poorly for others,** depending on the generator used. This
>   will be refined in the future. Do not rely on the order of text coming
>   out of this function, as it will change if this function is made more
>   sophisticated.

Summarizing: the method is implemented in a simplistic way and it won't get you what you want unless you are willing to dive into PDF structure documentation and improve the library. It would be a worthy gift to the community should you decide to do it.

Should you want to explore the alternatives - check a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837707/extracting-text-from-a-pdf-file-using-python).

Comment: @Shashi Shankar Singh - did it help? If so, could you please accept the answer?