# Any way to open pdf in chrome, select all, copy, and paste/write to file?

Tags: python, macos, pdf, osascript

I'm looking for a way to to open a pdf in chrome, select all, and copy the contents to write to a text file. I understand this is a very hacky approach, but I've tried `pdftotext` and `textract` libraries for reading pdf text already, and manually doing select all and copy/paste in chrome has read text in my multiple files most consistently.

This is what I have so far:

```
import os
import subprocess

# open file in chrome
cmd = """osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "a" using {command down}'"""
p = subprocess.Popen(['open', '-na', 'Google Chrome', '--args', '--new-window', f'{pdf_f}'])
time.sleep(1)
# select all
os.system(cmd)
time.sleep(1)
# copy
cmd = """osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "c" using {command down}'"""
os.system(cmd)
```

This visibly looks to work, opening the pdf in chrome then showing all of the text selected, but the text isn't being copied. I can't tell if its from the copy command or when the new chrome window opens, the focus is on the window and not on the pdf file within the window.

Comment: The extra hop of copying into chrome doesnt seem very efficient.  Have you evaluated other python pdfs libraries such as `PyPDF2` and the `PdfFileReader` class?  https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/#description.  Also, other helpful answers may be here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837707/how-to-extract-text-from-a-pdf-file

Comment: Yeah I tried those too, but unfortunately they weren't reading the text in a consistent manner with my files. I tried opening with a few different apps and chrome copied the text in the best way for me to parse the text later with regex, so decided to go that route.

Answer (score 2):

Found a way:

```
for fnm in fnms:
    pdf_f = path/'data'/'pdfs'/f'{fnm}'
    # open file in chrome
    p = subprocess.Popen(['open', '-na', 'Google Chrome', f'{pdf_f}'])
    time.sleep(1)
    # click
    pyautogui.moveTo(screen_width//2, screen_height//2)
    pyautogui.click()
    # select all
    pyautogui.hotkey('command', 'a')
    # copy
    pyautogui.hotkey('command', 'c')
    # write txt file
    clipboard_to_txt(path/'data'/'txts'/(fnm[:-3]+'txt'))
    # close tab
    pyautogui.hotkey('command', 'w')
```