# I have a problem understanding an error in Python

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAhSf.png)I am trying to open a basic `file.txt` file which is located in the same `CWD` as my python interpreter.

So I do `a=open("file.txt","r")`

Then I want to display its content (there's only one test line like `hello world` in it)

So I do `content=a.read()`

So you know, when I put `a` enter, I have this:

```py
a
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='fichier.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

Then I have an error I don't understand. Does someone have an idea on how to fix this ?

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    contenu=a.read()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc6 in position 15: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Can you show us what exactly your file contains? This error indicates that there's an invalid character in the file - specifically, the fifteenth character in the file. Fix that and this should run properly.

Comment: can you run `file -I fichier.txt` in the terminal and tell us the output?

Comment: It's always good to try to read a regular txt file with basic characters to see if there are some issues with the content.

Comment: Ok so I did a new doc with the .rtf extension. The text inside is "this file is vanilla. It only contains letters and dots.". Now python seems to read it, but doesn't display properly what's inside. Instead, I see

Comment: '{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\cocoartf1671\\cocoasubrtf200\n{\\fonttbl\\f0\\fswiss\\fcharset0 Helvetica;}\n{\\colortbl;\\red255\\green255\\blue255;}\n{\\*\\expandedcolortbl;;}\n\\paperw11900\\paperh16840\\margl1440\\margr1440\\vieww10800\\viewh8400\\viewkind0\n\\pard\\tx566\\tx1133\\tx1700\\tx2267\\tx2834\\tx3401\\tx3968\\tx4535\\tx5102\\tx5669\\tx6236\\tx6803\\pardirnatural\\partightenfactor0\n\n\\f0\\fs24 \\cf0 this file is vanilla. It only contains letters and dots.}'

Comment: Well I tried the same with a docx file containing the same content.

Comment: This time I have the error again saying
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    b=a.read()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd2 in position 16: invalid continuation byte

Comment: @SébastienChabrol can you run the command I said? Can you also run `xxd fichier.txt` and put the contents on pastebin or edit them into your question?

Comment: Opening a .rtf and a .docx as a raw text file isn't going to work. Unlike a .txt file that contains only text, those files contain a bunch of information besides the text (like where to render it, in what font) which should be read and parsed by a library, like for example [PyPDF2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837707/how-to-extract-text-from-a-pdf-file) or [textract](https://textract.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Answer (score 1):

Your file is probably not encoded in UTF-8. Try:

```
from chardet import detect

with open("file.txt", "rb") as infile:
    raw = infile.read()

    encoding = detect(raw)['encoding']  
    print(encoding)
```

Comment: You have to `pip3 install chardet` first

Comment: I don't have the "chardet" package. I have really no idea how to download it and link it to my python. I'm a beginner btw

Comment: Open up Terminal.app. You are now in a bash prompt. It's similar to the python prompt in your screenshot but it's used for controlling your computer. When you install Python it installs a bash command called `pip3` (the 3 is because this is Python 3) which is used for installing packages. To install a package you type `pip3 install <package name>`. In this case, `pip3 install chardet`. If that runs successfully, when you're back in the python prompt, you can do `import chardet` or `from chardet import detect`.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is not encoded in UTF-8.  The encoding is controlled by the tool used to create the file.  Make sure you use the right encoding.

Here's an example:

```
>>> s = 'Sébastien Chabrol'
>>> s.encode('utf8')             # é in UTF-8 is encoded as bytes C3 A9.
b'S\xc3\xa9bastien Chabrol'
>>> s.encode('cp1252')           # é in cp1252 is encoded as byte E9.
b'S\xe9bastien Chabrol'
>>> s.encode('utf8').decode('1252')  # decoding incorrectly can produce wrong characters...
'SÃ©bastien Chabrol'
>>> s.encode('cp1252').decode('utf8') # or just fail.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 1: invalid continuation byte
```

If using Python 3, you can provide the encoding when you open the file:

```
a = open('file.txt','r',encoding='utf8')
```

On Python 2 or 3, you can also use the backward-compatible syntax:

```
import io
a = io.open('file.txt','r',encoding='utf8')
```

If you have no idea of the encoding, you can open in binary mode to see the raw byte content and at least make a guess:

```
a = open('file.txt','rb')
print(a.read())
```

Read more about Python and encodings here: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html