# result shows file full of some symbols rather than text when I loop files

Tags: python-3.x, encoding

I was looping some files to copy the content of somes file to a new file but after I run the code, the result shows lot of symbols in the new file, not the text  content of the files I looped.

first, when I ran the code without putting the 'encoding' attribute in open file line, it showed an error message like,
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x8b' in position 12: character maps to .

I tried various encodings like utf-8,latin1 but nothing worked and when i put 'errors=ignore' in the open file line, then the result showed like I described above.

import os
import glob

folder = os.path.join('R:', os.sep, 'Files')

def notes():

```
for doc in glob.glob(folder + r'\*'):
    if doc.endswith('.pdf'):
        with open(doc,'r') as f:
            x = f.readlines()
        with open('doc1.text', 'w+') as f1:
            for line in x:
                f1.write(line)
```

notes()

Comment: which os you are using i was also facing such kind of problems on a old linux version

Comment: @Fabian windows 10

Comment: instead of using readmode r ? maybe use "rb"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your example correctly and you’re trying to read PDF files, your problem is not one of encoding but of file format. PDF files don’t just to store your text in coding materials are unique format that you need to be able to read in order to extract the text. There are a couple of python libraries that can read PDF files (such as Py2PDF), please refer to this thread for more information: [How to extract text from a PDF file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837707/how-to-extract-text-from-a-pdf-file)

Comment: i tried with .docx files too but the result is the same

Comment: @riki PDF's and DOCX's are ***binary files***, pass `'b'` switch to `open`

Comment: Again, docx files and pdf files have special Formats which you need to parse. You need to use a some library for that, like pydocx and py2pdf