# How can I extract text from a pdf using Python?

Tags: python, pdf, text, pdfminer

```
def extract_pdf(pdf_path):                     
    with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as fh:
    # iterate over all pages of PDF document
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fh, caching=True, check_extractable=True):
        # creating a resoure manager
        resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()

        # create a file handle
        fake_file_handle = StringIO()

        # creating a text converter object
        converter = TextConverter(
                            resource_manager, 
                            fake_file_handle, 
                            codec='utf-8', 
                            laparams=LAParams()
                    )

        # creating a page interpreter
        page_interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(
                            resource_manager, 
                            converter
                        )

        # process current page
        page_interpreter.process_page(page)

        # extract text
        text = fake_file_handle.getvalue()
        yield text

        # close open handles
        converter.close()
        fake_file_handle.close()

text = ''
for page in extract_pdf('Path of the PDF Document'): 
    text +=  page
```

Through this code, I was able to extract many PDF documents. but when I tested it on other random PDFs from the internet, it starts fluctuating and then the extracted text is not there as an output. When I checked the type of the text, it was showing `<class 'str'>`.

Can someone rectify any such errors which I had overlooked while writing this code?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837707/how-to-extract-text-from-a-pdf-file) might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

```
import PyPDF2 
o = open('example.pdf', 'rb') 
r = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(o)
for page in range(r.numPages):
    Obj = r.getPage(page)
    print Obj.extractText()
```