# How to retrieve particular table data in multiple tables from a PDF using python

Tags: python, excel, tabular, tabula, pdf-parsing

I have 100 annual reports of different banks. All these annual reports are of same format.I want to extract profit&loss table and balance sheet table from all the 100 PDFs and store in an excel file. Is there any way to do that using python?

Below is the code that is extracting all the tables In a PDF and saving in an excel file.

```
import tabula
from tabula import wrapper
from tabula import *
import PyPDF2,os,time
import pandas as pd

filename=input("enter pdf name")+".pdf"
pdf=PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(filename,"rb"))
pag_no=pdf.getNumPages()

for i in range(0,pag_no):
    pg=pdf.getPage(i)
    writer=PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
    writer.addPage(pg)
    NewPDFfilename="Page_"+str(i)+".pdf"
    with open(NewPDFfilename,"wb")as outputStream:
        writer.write(outputStream)

for i in range(0,pag_no):
    file=wrapper.convert_into('Page_'+str(i)+'.pdf,'result_'+str(i)+'.csv',output_format='csv')
    file=wrapper.convert_into('Page_'+str(i)+'.pdf,'result_'+str(i)+'.csv',output_format='xml')
    try:
        df=pd.read_csv("result_"+str(i)+".csv", sep=" ",header='none',delimiter=r"\s+")
        if(df.empty):
            print("yes")
        else:
            print("table found in --->PAGE"+str(i+1)+"and store in --->result_"+str(i)+".csv")
    except (pd.errors.EmptyDataError,FileNotFoundError):
        os.remove(r'Users\Downloads\Table-extraction-from-PDF-and-Images-master'+str(i)+'.pdf')
        os.remove(r'Users\Downloads\Table-extraction-from-PDF-and-Images-master'+str(i)+'.csv')
        pass
```

Comment: share what you have tried so far.

Comment: There is a previous answer here that should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837707/how-to-extract-text-from-a-pdf-file.  The problem you may have is that all the annual reports will probably be in different formats.  I suspect it may be cleaner to get an API that allows you to download financial statements

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But the link you provided is for text extraction from PDF. I want to extract the profit&loss table, balance sheet table