# unexpected keyword argument 'codec' in XMLConverter

Tags: python-3.x, codec, pdfminer, xmlconvert

**Below error message:**

```
device = XMLConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, laparams=laparams, codec=codec)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'codec'
```

**Original Code:**

```
rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
retstr = BytesIO()
codec = 'utf-8'
laparams = LAParams()
device = XMLConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, laparams=laparams, codec=codec)
```

This is surprisingly working fine in my project setup (python 3.5.3) but not in the new setup (python 3.7.4). Not sure if the this is anyways a problem or if a new version of XMLConverter is now available

Comment: which module do you get XMLConverter from? and what version do you have installed in each env?

Comment: If this is from PDFMiner then indeed the XMLConverter class doesnt have a keyword `codec` in its method signature in the current version. `def __init__(self, rsrcmgr, outfp, pageno=1, laparams=None, imagewriter=None, stripcontrol=False):`

Comment: Yes Chris, you are right. The current version doesn't have codec keyword. Though 20181108 version does, and that is what is used in the other environment (stable app)

Answer (score 5):

As suspected by chris, this issue is due to version mismatch. 2019 version of pdfminer doesn't have keyword codec in the method. So I installed the older version of pdfminer 20181108 which is used in my project as well. Now the code runs without any error

Comment: Also, note that there is pdfminer and pdfminer.six which the last have the codec argument.

Comment: `No matching distribution found for pdfminer==20181108` for windows. Hence you need to install `pdfminer.six==20181108` on windows.