# Unable to extract text from pdf file

Tags: python, nlp

I am trying to extract  text from pdf file. I have already checked that the file is not encrypted. Here is my code

```
import PyPDF2 as pdf
file=open("6683127-House-Rental-Contract-GERALDINE-GALINATO-v2-Page-1.pdf","rb")
pdf_reader=pdf.PdfFileReader(file)
page1=pdf_reader.getPage(0).extractText()
page1
```

I am getting output like this

```
'\n\n˘ˇˆ˙˛ˆ˚ˇ˜ ˆˆ˘!˘ˇ!˘ˇˇ"#\nˇ\n!`ˆ$ˆ$"##&ˆˇˆ˙ˆ\'$ˆ˘!\nˇ(\nˇˆ˝\n˙)ˆ˙˜ˇ˘˚ˆˇˆ˙\nˆˆˇ+ˇ"##,-.ˆ%ˇ˛"//0ˆ%ˇ˜ˆ˙ˆˇ˜ˆ˙ˆ˜˘!˘!ˇ\nˆ\n˛˚ ˝\nˇ\n"%#˛"%&˛\n˙)ˆ˙ˆ˜(ˇ˘˚ˆ˘!ˇˆ˙ˆˆˇ,ˆ˘)ˆ\n˙ˆ˛˙˙ˆ˜ˆ˘ˆˇˆ˙ˆ˜˘\nˇ ˝\n&%#(\n˛ˆˇ ˘ˇ˘ˇ\n"%%&˛\nˇ(4˜(˘ˆ\n\nˆ˘!6\n˙˝\n\'$˘ˇ\nˇ˛ˇ!(˙˙˘)6˙ˆˇ!ˆˇ\n)˝+,-˝.˝˙0\n˝1˝2˙˙\nˇ˚ ˘˚˘)ˇ\n,-.\nˇ\n˙\nˆ$ˆ%ˇ˛˙\n,-.\n\nˆˇ˚  ˘ˇ\n˛ ˘ˆˇ!7\n˘ˇ4˜˘˚˛ˆˇ(4˛ ˇˇ˘)ˇ ˇ˚ˇˆ˛ˇ$˜\'$\nˆ˙˘)˛ \n#%&(\n\n*ˆ$ˆ˘ˇˆ˙ˇ\n7˛8%$9:#8%$#$2˛2\n$ˆ\'˙˘!1ˆ˘˚\n,-\n.\n\n\n\n9&˛;˛%&˙#(\n8ˆ˙ˇ$˘ˇ˙˙ˇ˘˘)ˆ˚ˇ\n˘!˘ˇˆ˙˘ˆ˘˚$7˚ ˆ$!%ˆ˘ˇˆ˘)\'ˆ˙ˆ˘˚\n%ˆ˙ˇ*ˆ$˘ˇ7˚ ˆ$ˆ˙!˘)ˇ˙˙$˙ˆˇ˘*ˆ˘)\n˘ˇ)ˆ˛!˙ˇ\'ˆ˙ˆ˘˚!7˘˚ˇ˚ˇ˘!˘ˇˆ˙˘ˆ˘˚$˚!˜\n(˙˙ˆ˚!ˇ ˇ*ˆ$ˆ˙˙ˇˆ ˘ˇ7\n<ˇ\n=˚>ˇ=\n8ˆ˙ˇ*ˆ$ˇ $˘ˇˆ˙(ˇ˘ˇ)˛ˆ˚\n˚ˇ.2˘ˇˇ˙ˆ$˘ˆ˙ˇ$7\nˆˇ˙%ˆ˙ˇ˘ˇ4ˇ*ˆ$(ˇ˘ˇ˚!ˇ ˙˙ˇ˘ˇ(4\nˇˆ˘)  ˆˇ˙)ˆ˙ˆ˚ˇˇ˚ˇˇ˘ˇ4ˇ ˆ˘!<ˇ˚ˇ$\nˇ7\n#8&;$#2˛&(\n˘ˇ4ˆˇ*ˆ$ˆˇ˘ˇˆ \n7\n˛8%$9:#8%$#$2˛˜2\nˇ˚˘ˇ*˙˙\n˚*˙ˆ˘˚(ˇˇˇ˛ ˇˆ ˘ˇ7>+>\n>+-˝7˚ˇ$ˇ(˙˙!ˆˇ\nˇ˘!ˇˇ˘ˆ˘˚$ˇ˚ˆˇˇ(4ˆ˘$!ˆ ˆ!˘ˇ˚˜\nˆ˙˙*ˆ!*˙ˆ˚!ˇ˘ˇˇ˘ˇ7\n˙˛$˛92;˙#%&(\nˇˆ˙ˆ!1ˆ˘˚*ˆ$ ˘ˇ˘ˇˆ˘!ˇ˛ˇ\n˚˛ˆ˚ˇ.>ˆˇ˙ˆˇ&!ˆˇ!ˆˇ ˘)@˘7ˆ%ˇ˛˜ $˘ˇ\n*ˆ$ ˘ˇ ˇ*ˆ!\'$>>*ˆ$ˆ\'˙ˇ\n%&˛%˛#:;\n%"#\n˙ˆˇ˚˚5!ˆ˘!ˇ!!7)ˆ˛!˙˚ˆ˜\n˛ˆˇ˙*ˆ$ ˘ˇ ˆ$ˆ%ˇ˛(ˆ ˆ\'$˚˚57˚ˇ!(˙˙\nˇ!7˘ˇ4(˙˙!\'$ˆ/!ˆ$˚˜ˆ˘!(˙˙!ˇ*ˆ$ˇ\nˆ ˆ\n'`
```

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837707/how-to-extract-text-from-a-pdf-file)solution is applicable in your case.