# python split long output string based on pattern (no delimiter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, split

I am new to python and I tried to read a PDF map using (PyPDF2). I am getting this as output [Sample output of pdf map as text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjfNS.png). I want to extract the data from this output where a certain pattern matches [RIY-DIRAHH-015524.49121946.651068]. I need only those values which only have this pattern. The length of the pattern varies [30-34]. Fixed for [RIY-DIRAHH-0155] while change only happens in LAT/LONG [24.49121946.651068]. [Complete output of PDF MAP](https://pastebin.com/uS9sxbe3).

Please help to extract/split the specific values (matches pattern). If there is any other solution available for reading PDF MAP. kindly advise. Thanks in advance.

```
import re
x='result of PDF map'[image1]
result = re.search('\w{3}-\w{6}-\d*.\d*.\d*',x)
#output
['', '', '', '', '']
```

[Sample Image of map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewNMn.png).

Comment: Could you please add sample input (and expected output) as text?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837707/how-to-extract-text-from-a-pdf-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract text from a PDF file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837707/how-to-extract-text-from-a-pdf-file)

Comment: Please have a look,  [Link](https://pastebin.com/xMg2wNEK). I want to extract only this,  starting and ending text need to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a regex that would work for you:

```
re.findall(r"RIY-[A-Z]{6}-\d{6}\.\d{8}\.\d{5,7}", text)
```

The result is:

```
 'RIY-OUHOMH-100224.53476846.650127',
 'RIY-OUHOMH-100324.53282546.65039',
 'RIY-OUHOMH-100424.53224446.651758',
 'RIY-OUHOHH-100724.52902946.653571',
 'RIY-OUHOHH-100624.53007146.651934',
 'RIY-OUHOHH-100524.53178646.65279',
 'RIY-OUHOMH-100124.53597246.649456',
 'RIY-DIRAHH-015124.49540746.641877',
 'RIY-DIRAHH-015224.49410546.644253',
 'RIY-DIRAHH-015324.49267846.646789',
 'RIY-DIRAHH-015424.49144946.649107',
 'RIY-DIRAHH-015524.49121946.651068',
 'RIY-DIRAHH-015624.49343446.652505',
 'RIY-DIRAHH-015724.49563146.653924',
 ...
```

### edit

To separate this into several columns, the entire code would be:

```
out = re.findall(r"RIY-[A-Z]{6}-\d{6}\.\d{6,8}\.\d{5,7}", text) 
df = pd.DataFrame(out, columns = ["RIY"]) 

df["col1"] = df.RIY.str[0:15]
df["col2"] = df.RIY.str[15:24]
df["col3"] = df.RIY.str[24:]
```

`df` would then look like:

```
                                 RIY             col1       col2       col3
0  RIY-OUHOMH-100224.53476846.650127  RIY-OUHOMH-1002  24.534768  46.650127
1   RIY-OUHOMH-100324.53282546.65039  RIY-OUHOMH-1003  24.532825   46.65039
2  RIY-OUHOMH-100424.53224446.651758  RIY-OUHOMH-1004  24.532244  46.651758
3  RIY-OUHOHH-100724.52902946.653571  RIY-OUHOHH-1007  24.529029  46.653571
4  RIY-OUHOHH-100624.53007146.651934  RIY-OUHOHH-1006  24.530071  46.651934
```

Comment: Bundle of Thanks, Dear. is is posible to separate

This 'RIY-OUHOMH-100124.53597246.649456'

to
 'RIY-OUHOMH-1001'
 '24.535972'
 '46.649456'

Comment: what do you mean by separating this? Break it into a tuple of (1) RIY, (2) OUHOMH, (3) 100124, etc?

Comment: Separating means for each element in output I want to split into 3 columns

From this RIY-DIRAHH-015724.49563146.653924 to


Col1 (RIY-DIRAHH-0157)   Col2 (24.495631)   Col3 (46.653924)

Comment: sure. If the text of a given item is 't', use: col1 = t[0:15]
col2 = t[15:24]
col3 = t[24:]

Comment: I am trying this to achieve 

From this RIY-DIRAHH-015724.49563146.653924 
to

Col1 (RIY-DIRAHH-0157) Col2 (24.495631) Col3 (46.653924) 




`import re`

`out = re.findall(r"RIY-[A-Z]{6}-\d{6}\.\d{6,8}\.\d{5,7}", text)`

`import pandas as pd`

`df=pd.DataFrame(out)`
`df.set_axis(['Raw_Data'], axis=1, inplace=False)`

`df.extract('("RIY-[A-Z]{6}") - ("\d{6}\.\d{6,8}\.\d{5,7}"+)',  expand=True)`


Error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'extract'

Comment: Thanks Again. This is happening for some rows for this data set. I think fix length split will only work perfectly for a fixed range. For the first part, [0:15] length will not change but for the rest of the part, length varies. I want to try (find second dot(.) -2 (to avoid removing 46) then split. I spent some time searching but did not found. 


` ".".join(aa.split(".", 2)[:2]) `

[Link](https://pastebin.com/4QeJiFW9)

Comment: Do you mind opening a new question about splitting the RIY column? SO doesn't encourage this kind of discussion that isn't part of the original question. Please tag me in a comment, and I promise to have a look ASAP. okay?