# How to convert bytes from PDF to string in Python?

Tags: python, python-requests, decode

I am trying to convert bytes which I get from `book_download_page = requests.get(link)` then `content = book_download_page.content` into string.

What I have tried,

```
content = book_download_page.content.decode('utf-8')
```

Error I get,

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 10: invalid continuation byte
```

Edit-
You can try [this link](http://93.174.95.29/main/460000/e7ff27044ecb85394ab8a4db0cf9b848/Yann%20Martel%20-%20Life%20of%20Pi%20%282003%29.pdf) for downloading

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract text from a PDF file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837707/how-to-extract-text-from-a-pdf-file)

Comment: Try other decodings like 'latin-1' and please give link will check and give you solution

Answer (score 1):

PDF contents are made up of tokens, see here:

[Adobe PDF Reference](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/pdf_reference_archives/PDFReference.pdf)

You can parse PDFs and extract text, with tools like PoDoFo in C++, PDFBox in Java, and there is also a PDF text stripper in Python.

```
import pdfbox

pdf_ref = pdfbox.PDFBox()
pdf_ref.extract_text('directory/originalPDF.pdf')   # Result .txt will be in directory/originalPDF.txt
```

Simple example paraphrased from [python-pdfbox](https://pypi.org/project/python-pdfbox/) in case if you want to convert other things like images too.