# PyPDF2 extracts blank text

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I am trying to extract Text from PyPDF2, but it's extracting blank Text from the PDF. The PDF is textual and not Image-based.
Is there any way to generalize the pdf so that it extracts the text? Bcoz I don't wanna change the library my whole code depends upon it. Otherwise, I'd have to rewrite the entire 2000+ lines of code.
Find the pdf here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aoWtxNhOKwFw2xbBZgv3gzZPOvt5Ovhc/view?usp=sharing

```
import PyPDF2
pdf_file = open('sample.pdf', 'rb')
read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
page = read_pdf.getPage(0)
page_content = page.extractText()
```

Comment: You might want to share the pdf in question to make helping you easier.

Comment: Hi, you can find the pdf here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aoWtxNhOKwFw2xbBZgv3gzZPOvt5Ovhc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: A quick inspection of the PDF suggests that extracting blank text is an error. Your PDF does contain information for text extraction. I haven't checked whether it's completely correct, but no output indicates an error in the text extraction routine.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It's an error of the PyPDF2. And it's not the one PDF I do have hundreds of PDFs on which it is not working. Maybe a particular type of PDF is acceptable by PyPDF2 library or something else.

Answer (score 1):

`extractText()` still has problems extracting the text properly. you can use another library called `slate`:

Install slate:

```
pip install slate3k
```

extract text:

```
with open('G10.pdf','rb') as f:
    extracted_text = slate.PDF(f)
print(extracted_text)
```

you can go through this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203414/pypdf-unable-to-extract-text-from-some-pages-in-my-pdf) too.

Comment: I don't wanna change the library, the whole 2500+ lines of code depends upon it.