# How to resolve UTF-8 encoding issues in python strings while extracting data from pdf?

Tags: python, string, encoding, text-extraction, pypdf

I used PyPDF2 to extract text from a PDF file.
This is the code I wrote.

```
import PyPDF2  as pdf
file = open("file_to_scrape.pdf",'rb')
pdf_reader = pdf.PdfFileReader(file)
page_1 = pdf_reader.getPage(0)
print(page_1.extractText())
```

This gave out the following output.

˜˚Power: An Enabler for Industrialization
and Regional Cooperation
˜˚.˜ Introduction

The weird characters behind Power and Introduction are supposed to be numbers, 15 and 15.1 to be precise.

I copied them and tried to encode them to utf-8, but this is what I got.

```
b'\xcb\x9c\xcb\x9aPower: An Enabler for Industrialization and Regional Cooperation\xcb\x9c\xcb\x9a.\xcb\x9c Introduction'
```

[THis is how the page looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDSPS.png) 
Could someone please help in figuring out this issue? My aim is to extract list of all figures, headings in the PDF along with their numbering

Comment: Try to see this related topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203414/pypdf-unable-to-extract-text-from-some-pages-in-my-pdf See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4203729/11777096

Comment: Why are you converting them to a different encoding in the first place? If the PDF extractor can't extract the information then you can't hope to conjure it out of thin air.